# Retrieve constantly from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

I am doing this animation tool where I fetch a value from my database and then a picture will animate to a certain position. My question is if it is possible to retrieve data constantly or like every 5 seconds?

Somehow like this:

```
while(autoretreive){
$data = mysql_query("select * from ......");
}
```

UPDATED from here

Thanks for your answers! Made it a little bit clearer what to do! Maybe I can explain better what I'm doing in my code.

I am doing this animation program as said, where balls with information is moving around to different locations. I have one value that will be updated frequently in the database, lets call it 'city'.

First at previous page I post the balls of information I want based on the 'city' and I do like this (simplified):

```
$pid = $_POST['id'];
$pcity[0] = $_POST['city'];
$pcity[1] = $_POST['city'];
$pcity[2] = $_POST['city'];
//...

$while(autoretrieve) { // HOW TO? 

$data = mysql_query(select * from table where city == $pcity[0] OR $pcity == [1] //...);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

$city = $rows['city'];
$id = $rows['id'];

if($city == example1){
"animate to certain pos"; //attached to image
}
else if($city == example2){
"animate to certain pos"; //attached to image
}
}
}
```

So for every update in the database the image will animate to a new position. So a time interval of 5 seconds would be great. I'm not an expert in coding so sorry for deprecated code. Not so familiar with AJAX either so what is going to be imported to the code? It is also important that the page is not reloading. Just the fetch from database.

Comment: you could use ajax to call your php script every 5 seconds

Comment: Or just select all the values first and store them in an array, then write an algorithm to update the position with the next value in the array every 5 seconds

Comment: This needs to be done at the client, with a simple page that returns the data that can be called regularly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with ajax and javascript 
make one javascript function which contains ajax code to retrive data from database

and at your page load using setTimeout call your ajax function at every 5 second

Answer (score -1):

You can use [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function to control how often you want to fetch data.

```
while(autoretreive){
  $data = mysql_query("select * from ......");
  //output your data here, check more in link about server sent events bellow
  sleep(5);
}
```

Since you haven't specified how you plan to access data I'm writing this answer assuming [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) as they are only ones that make sense according to your question.

Now all this was according to your question which wasn't very clear on how do you plan to use data. Again you'll most likely want to fetch data using ajax, but Server Sent Events can also be a good way you could achieve this.

And don't use mysql_* it's deprecated, switch to PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: Even if this is answer to your question probably ajax option is what you really need.

Comment: That will wait 5 seconds between each query, not send them back to the client every 5 seconds.  It will basically make the server response hang until !autoretrieve.

Comment: @Archer it was generic example for the OP, but if you want to go in more details it is possible using  [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) for example.

Comment: Sorry, but it's a terrible example, unless you believe that he's asking for the server to never return the page.

Comment: Then please update your answer to reflect this.  At the moment the code you've supplied will cause a timeout error.

Comment: @Archer I hope you get clearer picture of my original thought now. I do not want to write complete code, just example where to put it and link should be sufficient.